# Removing specific value from array (java)

Tags: java, arrays

i have integer a = 4 and array b 7,8,9,4,3,4,4,2,1

i have to write a method that removes int ALL a from array b

desired result 7,8,9,3,2,1

This is what I have so far,

```
    public static int[] removeTwo (int x, int[] array3)
{
    int counter = 0;
    boolean[] barray = new boolean [array3.length];
    for (int k=0; k<array3.length; k++)
    {
        barray[k] = (x == array3[k]);
        counter++;
    }

     int[] array4 = new int [array3.length - counter];
     int num = 0;
     for (int j=0; j<array3.length; j++)
{
     if(barray[j] == false)
    {
        array4[num] = array3[j];
        num++;
    }

}
     return array4;
```

I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Utility.removeTwo(Utility.java:50)
    at Utility.main(Utility.java:18)
```

Java Result: 1

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You're incrementing counter on each step through the first for loop, is that really what you mean?

Comment: Is there any good reason why you dont use the ListArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error stems from this for loop:

```
for (int k=0; k<array3.length; k++)
{
    barray[k] = (x == array3[k]);
    counter++;
}
```

when you create `int[] array4 = new int [array3.length - counter];` you are creating an array with size 0. You should only increment the counter if the item is the desired item to remove:

```
for (int k=0; k<array3.length; k++)
{
    boolean b = (x == array3[k]);
    barray[k] = b;
    if(b) {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

To answer your question in the comment, the method should be called and can be checked like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array3 = {0,1,3,2,3,0,3,1};
    int x = 3;
    int[] result = removeTwo(x, array3);
    for (int n : result) {
        System.out.print(""+ n + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: It got rid of the error but i still got int x in my array
int [] array3 = {0,1,3,2,3,0,3,1};
        int x = 3;
        
        removeTwo(x,array3);
        for (int value : array3)
            System.out.printf("%d",value);

Do I use that in my main method?

Comment: Use what in your main method?  Why would you print the values of array3, which seems to be the original array?

Comment: wait nevermind, I wasn't thinking straight. hahaha I need sleep, thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure thing, it happens!

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
 int[] array4 = new int [array3.length - counter];
```

You create an array with size 0, as `counter` is equal to `array3.length` at this point.

This means that you cannot access any index in that array.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating

```
int[] array4 = new int [array3.length - counter];// 0 length array.
```

you can't have `0th` index there. At least length should `1` to have `0th` index.

BTW my suggestion, it is better to use `List`. Then you can do this easy.

Answer (score 0):

Really an Array is the wrong tool for the job, since quite apart from anything else you will end up with stray values at the end that you cannot remove. Just use an ArrayList and that provides a removeAll() method to do what you need. If you really need arrays you can even do:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(array))
list.removeAll(4);
array = list.toArray();
```

(Exact method names/parameters may need tweaking as that is all from memory).

Comment: Is there any method removeAll(int) at `List`?

Comment: int is a primitive object, you can't put that in a `List`

Comment: @TimB that's why he is using `Integer`

Comment: @Stone I know, I was telling Masud :)

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to work with a second array where you put in the correct values

something likte that

```
public static int[] removeTwo (int x, int[] array3)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int[] array4 = new int[array3.lenght];
    for (int i = 0; i < array3.lenght; i ++) {
       if(array3[i] == x){
           array4[counter] = array3[i];
       }
    }
    return array4;
}
```

anoterh way is to remove the `x` calue from the `array3` and shift the values behind forward

Comment: This code would not work, you never increment `counter` and you also misspelled length twice.

Comment: you are right sorry. 

after `array4[counter] = array3[i];` you have to increment the counter `counter += 1`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to remove element from array is to use `List` with `Iterator`. Try,

```
 Integer[] array = {7, 8, 9, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1};
 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(array));
 for(Iterator<Integer> it=list.iterator();it.hasNext();){
     if(it.next()==4){
        it.remove();
      }
  }
```